# Android : Notification sound disable

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification with this code :

```
Notification notifica = new Notification();
notifica.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notifica.icon = R.drawable.serie_notification;
notifica.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

with **notifica.defaults = notifica.defaults|Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;** I enable the default sound but if I want to disable the sound how can I do ??

Comment: I thought it was disabled by default. I don't remember it making a  sound on the notification I made...

Comment: There's a bug in the Notification Channels when targeting API 26 (Android O) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a notification without a sound java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809702/how-to-show-a-notification-without-a-sound-java)

Answer (score 20):

Well, it worked for me by doing this:

```
myNotification.defaults = 0;
```

Try it out =)

Comment: Yes, set `defaults` to 0 and `sound` to `null`.

Comment: where i assign mynotification.defaults = 0

Comment: This no longer works when targeting Android O. There's no way to disable the sound.

Comment: @Daniel F For Android O, use `NotificationChannel` and set the importance to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` then it won't make sounds.

Comment: @BedrockDev Yes, thanks. I'm aware of this. You may want to flag this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65108694

Comment: @Bedrock Dev NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW certainly does not work on Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0.  Sound is still played.

Answer (score 13):

> To show notifications without sound on pre Oreo devices, Oreo and above devices

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertDetails.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";

    // You must create the channel to show the notification on Android 8.0 and higher versions
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Set importance to IMPORTANCE_LOW to mute notification sound on Android 8.0 and above
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            // You must set the priority to support Android 7.1 and lower
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW) // Set priority to PRIORITY_LOW to mute notification sound 
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true); 

    notificationManager.notify(
                    1001, // notification id
                    mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 8):

NotificationCompat.Builder method

```
setSilent(true)
```

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to do that basically just enable all of the other `Notification.defaults` except the sound ( which is `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND` ).

Here is an example that will work for you:

```
myNotification.defaults = 0;
myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Here are all of the available the options you can select:

```
Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
Notification.DEFAULT_ALL // This enables all above 3
```

**Update**

Notification `.defaults` deprecated

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of Android, u have to set the prioirity of notification channel to low:

```
var channel = new NotificationChannel(notificationChannelName, "channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Comment: Setting IMPORTANCE_LOW will not work to disable the sound

Answer (score 2):

android "O" >= , Disable or Enable sound of the notification you use two ids for notification channel.
one for sounded notification and another is set when you want to disable

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChannel(Context context, NotificationManager mNotificationManager, boolean playSound) {
```

`// The user-visible name of the channel.
    CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.channel_name);

    // The user-visible description of the channel.

    String description = context.getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(playSound ? channel_id_sound : channel_id_no_sound, name, importance);

    // Configure the notification channel.
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);

    // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
    // channel, if the device supports this feature.
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    if (!playSound)
        mChannel.setSound(null, null);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the sound using this

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

Just set the sound of channel as null

Answer (score 0):

For silent notification sound for any motification importances.

Save to `raw` folder silent sound. Duration may be 0.01s for low size.

For `SDK >= 28` use notification channel (before create):

```
channel.setSound( Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.silent ), null );
```

For other SDK use:

```
notification_builder.setSound( Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.silent ) );
```