# Android disable notification sounds

Tags: android, notifications

I want to create a notification without any sounds. How can I do this?
I tried the code below but it's not working for me:

```
notification = mBuilder
        .setStyle(notiStyle)
        .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)
        .setTicker(title)
        .setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setSound(null).build();
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655164/android-notification-sound-disable

Comment: There's a bug in the Notification Channels when targeting API 26 (Android O) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the `NotificationCompat.Builder`  object without using `setSound()`. This will create a notification without any sound.

```
notification = mBuilder
                .setStyle(notiStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

After your notification builder, add

```
notification.defaults = 0;
```

to tell the notification manager not to make any default values when not specified (eg. you set to null so it takes the default value, adding this will remove this behavior and so disable sounds completely).

Comment: in android o its removed

Comment: @Sakiboy the sound comes from the channel when you set the importance of the notification channel to low it should not play sound ,but when you create channel in the first time you cant created it again it stays in  the device you need to remove change through apis or create anew channel name

Comment: Right. So it’d be a good idea to handle these things with care when creating them (turn off all the sounds and vibrations?) Also `setAlertOnlyOnce()` works for notifications that update, this could be helpful in certain places. Since you can’t update you’re actual notification object.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 26+ (Oreo) you do this by setting notification channel importance level to 'IMPORTANCE_LOW' or below.

```
val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
    description = descriptionText
}
```

Comment: important_low make bubble not show