# Trigger Push Notification without sound

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an application based on Push Notifications (Custom Notifications). I am using `FCM` and `javascript (index.js)`. I am able to trigger push notification perfectly but the problem is sound. I want Push Notification with Sound in one condition (`if`) and without Sound in other (`else`). What is happening is, in both conditions I am getting sound. How can I trigger a push notification without sound?

```
String remoteMessageSound = remoteMessageData.get(REMOTE_SOUND);
            if (remoteMessageSound.equals("default")) {
                Notification notificationDefault = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.namma_apartment_notification)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .build();

                Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(mNotificationID, notificationDefault);
            } else {
                Notification notificationNoSound = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.namma_apartment_notification)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setSound(null)
                        .setPriority(PRIORITY_LOW)
                        .build();

                Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(mNotificationID, notificationNoSound);
            }
```

And this is my index.js:

```
if (cabNotificationSound) {
            payload = {
                data: {
                    message: "Your Cab has " + status + " your society.",
                    "sound": "default",
                    type: "Cab_Notification"
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            payload = {
                data: {
                    message: "Your Cab has " + status + " your society.",
                    "sound": "",
                    type: "Cab_Notification"
                }
            };
        }


        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload).then(result => {
            return console.log("Notification sent");
        });
```

Comment: I take it you read somewhere that `setSound(null)` turns sound OFF? how about if you don't use setSound *at all*, does that do it?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899789/android-disable-notification-sounds perhaps? (i.e. DONT call .setSound seems to be the answer)

Comment: No. It still sends sound even if we don't use setSound() at all.

Comment: perhaps it's related [to this bug discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel)

Comment: remove  .setSound(null)

Comment: @ShivamKumar It doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to setSound(null, null) on notification channel instead of the notification itself?

Comment: @JaviMollá No. But how do we do it? Can you please post a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to set the sound directly in the channel before sending the notification (**for api >= 26**):

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id));
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

Comment: What about api <= 26?

Comment: Api < 26 does not have notification channels and you should set the sound on the notification, like you're already doing

Comment: But that's not working. Your solution works for api>=26. But <=26, its not working even if you setSound(null), or even if you dont put setSound() at all

Comment: Add setDefaults(0) to NotificationCompat.Builder