# Foreground Service with a Silent Notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, foreground-service

**Context:**

I have been using Google's [LocationUpdatesForegroundService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService) example project to learn a bit more about services.

I have downloaded the project via Github desktop and ran it on my phone, everything is great and the project does what it's intended to do.

*My phone is Android 8.0.0, API 26*

**Problem:**

The foreground service notification shows up on the status bar once the app is terminated, as soon as that happens I hear a notification sound(default sound).
However, I would like the notification to be silent, like in some location-based apps(eg: [Life360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd&hl))

**What I've tried so far:**

- in [LocationUpdatesService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java) at added`159` tried `mChannel.setSound(null,null);`
- in [LocationUpdatesService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java) at line `296` changed `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)` to 
  `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)`
- in [LocationUpdatesService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java) at line `158`changed `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)`
- in [LocationUpdatesService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java) at  line `300` added `setSound(null)`

None of the above have worked for me, I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this situation.

Comment: Are you calling notification in startForground(id, notification); function?

Comment: @hfarhanahmed Yes in [LocationUpdatesService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java#L226) at line 226

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809702/how-to-show-a-notification-without-a-sound-java check this solution

Comment: the code I use doesn't even have `builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);`

Comment: add .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL); after line 298 in  LocationUpdatesService.java

Comment: @hfarhanahmed Nope, still makes a notification sound.

Comment: The solution is to use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW and create a new channel for it. Once a channel is created, you can't change the importance (well, you can, but the new importance is ignored). The channel information appears to get stored permanently by the system and any channel created is only deleted when you uninstall the app. you can delete the channel via nm.deleteNotificationChannel(nChannel.getId()); and recreate it with nm.createNotificationChannel(nChannel);
via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel/45920861

Comment: @hfarhanahmed I have already tried that as I stated in my question.

Comment: did you changed the channel name as well??

Comment: @hfarhanahmed I didn't create any new channels I just set the importance to `IMPORTANCE_LOW` when I was creating the INITIAL channel

Comment: try creating a different channel, I thing you are doing everything correct.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed This solved my issue please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable sound from NotificationChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a notification without a sound java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809702/how-to-show-a-notification-without-a-sound-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW and create a new channel for it. Once a channel is created, you can't change the importance (well, you can, but the new importance is ignored). The channel information appears to get stored permanently by the system and any channel created is only deleted when you uninstall the app. you can delete the channel as

```
nm.deleteNotificationChannel(nChannel.getId());
```

and recreate it with

```
nm.createNotificationChannel(nChannel);
```

via stack overflow answer here [Disable sound from NotificationChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel/45920861)

Comment: Don't just copy/paste answers from another question. Instead flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: @tir38 Okay, sorry I am new to giving answers. will do it next time.

Answer (score 3):

In the LocationUpdatesForegroundService, when the service is onUnbind, it will invoke 'startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())', then the Notification will show with sound.  So you need to change the NotificationChannel follow the below code

```
mChannel.setSound(null, null);
mChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Answer (score 1):

mChannel.setSound(null,null) will do it, but you need to uninstall/reinstall the app for it to take effect. Or changing CHANNEL_ID to a different value will also recreate channel with updated setting.

Comment: you'll likely go with changing CHANNEL_ID in production

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late with answer, but did you try reinstalling the app? It's simple and it may fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late to answer this question
but for other seaker for an answer, i will add my answer:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
                      NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
   .setSilent(true);
```