# How to display the notification without playing any sound

Tags: java, android

I need to show a notification without playing a notification sound
using notification builder.

I tried using

```
set sound(null);
```

And I have also tried using the custom sound

Here is my code:

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification() {
   getData();
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
            .setContentTitle(time)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setDefaults(0)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSound(null);

}
```

Comment: Which android version you try to off sound

Comment: @AnasMehar, it is a mulit-version app

Comment: @gaspar do you try this setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) instead .setDefaults(0)

Comment: @Mohsinkazi, yes and it is still playing the sound

Comment: @gaspar in which version you are testing

Comment: @gaspar For O version n above add channel.setSound(null,null) after creating NotificationChannel channel.

Comment: @Mohsinkazi, thank you, but what do I do for the versions that are lower then the O?

Comment: @gaspar for versions lower than O your code is correct (.setSound(null) or setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) ) according to me.

Comment: @gaspar Is your problem sloved?

Comment: @Mohsinkazi, unfortunately.... No

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a notification without a sound java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809702/how-to-show-a-notification-without-a-sound-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line to `builder.setDefaults(0);` . It will not play the sound, but you may need to enable all other notification defaults if preferred