# Android 8.0 Double Notification Sound

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Update: I solved it by setting

```
            .setGroupAlertBehavior(GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)
```

I am creating notifications like

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
            .setColor(..)
            .setContentTitle(..)
            .setSubText(..)
            .setSmallIcon(..)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setGroup(groupKey)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .build();
```

On 8.0 some devices are seeing double notification sound for every notification. [There is a blog post around this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/7OV8ByN0TIY;context-place=topicsearchin/nexus/category$3Amanaging-accounts-and-settings%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false)

Some apps seem to have figured out a way to solve the issue? Help!

Comment: Did you find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .setGroupAlertBehavior(GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)

Comment: works only if you set group for your notifications (look at my answer)

Answer (score -1):

Because of new "Notification channels" introduced in android O, you need to create notification channel and set `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` to it.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45920861/6455647)

Comment: I don't like this solution because it creates an extra category. I think .setGroupAlertBehavior(GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY) works well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define [notifications Group](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group).
then, you need to set the setGroupAlertBehavior, like @Anand Khinvasara's answer

```
notificationBuilder.setGroup("com.YOUR_PACKAGE_ID.NOTIFICATIONS_GROUP");
notificationBuilder.setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY);
```