# Disable notification sound on Android O

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I try to get rid of the **notification sound** in below method.

I was able to *reduced it to only go off once* but it should be **completely silent in Android O** and lower versions.

I searched a long time on stackoverflow and google but till now nothing completely works.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public void showUpdateProgressNotification(int id, String appName, int progress, String status, long downloadStart) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel
                    (NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Test Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel test");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_FILE_CANCEL);
        cancelIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent cancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ACTION_FILE_CANCEL.hashCode() + id,
                cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(appName)
                .setContentText(status)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyApplication_.getInstance().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setProgress(100, progress, progress == 0)
                .setWhen(downloadStart)
                .setContentIntent(cancel)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp, "Cancel", cancel)
                .setColor(MyApplication_.getInstance().getResources().getColor(R.color.apps_color))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(status);
        notification.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());

        addNotification(id);
 }
```

Comment: More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919392/disable-sound-from-notificationchannel

Comment: You need to uninstall the app and reinstall it as once the notification channel is created with the sound , it will not be override. Hence you need to uninstall the app and install again.

Answer (score 55):

I figured it out after some more research.

This is the vital part:

```
//Configure the notification channel, NO SOUND
notificationChannel.setDescription("no sound");
notificationChannel.setSound(null,null); <---- ignore sound
notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
```

At first on implementing this, it still did not work but **after uninstalling my app, and reinstall it** everything was fine.

If any one needs it, here is the correct code:

```
public void showUpdateProgressNotification(int id, String appName, int progress, String status, long downloadStart) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My app no sound", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );

            //Configure the notification channel, NO SOUND
            notificationChannel.setDescription("no sound");
            notificationChannel.setSound(null,null);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_FILE_CANCEL);
        cancelIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent cancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ACTION_FILE_CANCEL.hashCode() + id,
                cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(appName)
                .setContentText(status)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyApplication_.getInstance().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setProgress(100, progress, progress == 0)
                .setWhen(downloadStart)
                .setContentIntent(cancel)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp, "Cancel", cancel)
                .setColor(MyApplication_.getInstance().getResources().getColor(R.color.apps_color));

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(status);
        notification.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());

        addNotification(id);
    }
```

Comment: applied your code, even uninstall and reinstall, it still have sound in my device (I send message from Firebase console, with sound option enable).

Comment: not worked when i just copy and paste the code and run.
But after uninstalling the app and install again it work. 
Thanks..

Comment: !!REINSTALL APP WORKS!!

Answer (score 8):

The following **never** makes a sound regardless of the source channel setting.

`NotificationCompat.Builder.setSilent(true)`

This allows you to have channel that makes sound by default while simultaneously posting silent notifications for individual ones without making the entire channel silent.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setSilent(boolean)

Answer (score 5):

Just add

```
NotificationCompat.Builder.setNotificationSilent()
```

**This works in all Android versions, in all cases even if you set PRIORITY_HIGH**

Make sure to uninstall app and install again

Example:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText("text")
                .setContentTitle("content")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setNotificationSilent() // just keep this line
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTicker("text"))

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your notification channel just set

```
notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
```