# How to disable notification sound with keeping heads up notification?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, native

#### I want

I'm noob for android.

My app displays heads up notification.
Now, my app always ringing when it listen notification regardless silent mode ON/OFF.

I want to do next things.

Disable notification sound with keeping heads up notification in silent mode.

---

Thanks for your help.

#### Problem

My app ringing when silent mode.

#### code

###### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
val channel = NotificationChannel(
    notificationType.channelId,
    notificationType.channelName,
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
).apply {
    setSound(uri, attribute)
    enableVibration(true)
    vibrationPattern = createVibrate()
    lightColor = Color.BLUE
}
channel.lockscreenVisibNotification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
```

###### PushNotificationListenerService.kt

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationComBuilder(this, receivedChannelId)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(text)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_logo)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
    .setCategory(CATEGORY_CALL)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setVibrate(createVibrate())
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 5000, 10)
```

#### things I tried

- Switch `setSound` settings corresponding to silent mode. (This is not working.)
- Try to set `notificationBuilder.setSilent(true)`. (Heads up notification deleted.)
- Try to change `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` to IMPORTANCE_LOW. (Heads up notification deleted.)

#### Else info

###### versions

```
kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
navigation_version = "2.3.5"
activity_version = "1.2.3"
fragment_version = "1.3.6"

compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

###### devise version

```
devise name: AQUOS sense4 basic
devise android version: 10
```

###### devise notification setting

```
all ON
```

Comment: This will be helpful you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54785422/10954249 and use audio manager to check whether sound settings is in ring or silent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : Notification sound disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655164/android-notification-sound-disable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by https://stackoverflow.com/a/54785422/14019506

Thanks for [DeePanShu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10954249/deepanshu).

Answer (score 0):

```
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

will disable sound for notification